# Async method is not executed in tests when running CI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm adding a new feature to my application that sends an async event everytime a search is made, I wrote an integration test for checking that everything is working fine, and it is, but only in my local machine. When I push the changes to the pipeline is consistenly failing by a timeout waiting for the data to be there (the result of the async method).

Here is my async config:

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableMethodSecurity
@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient() {
        return WebClient.builder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("MyAsyncTask");
    }
}
```

My Controller where I send the async event:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<TobaccoContentResponse>> find(
    @RequestParam(value = "query", defaultValue = "", required = false) String query,
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "", required = false) Map<String, String> flavors,
    HttpServletRequest request) {
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new SearchEvent(
            this,
            request.getHeader("User-Agent"),
            RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request).getCountry(),
            flavors.keySet(),
            Instant.now()
        ));
        // do stuff
}
```

...my listener:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SearchListener {

    private final FlavorRepository flavorRepository;
    private final SearchRepository searchRepository;

    @Async
    @EventListener
    @Transactional
    public void newSearch(SearchEvent searchEvent) {
        log.info("New search received");
        var flavors = flavorRepository.findAllByCodeIn(searchEvent.getFlavorCodes());
        var search = new Search(
            null,
            searchEvent.getUserAgent(),
            searchEvent.getRegion(),
            new HashSet<>(flavors),
            searchEvent.getCreatedAt()
        );
        searchRepository.save(search);
        log.info("New search {} registered", search.getId());
    }
}
```

And finally my test:

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    tobaccoRepository.deleteAll();
    searchRepository.deleteAll();
}

@Test
void shouldFindTobaccosByFlavor() {
    var manufacturer = ManufacturerBuilder.builder().build();
    manufacturerRepository.save(manufacturer);
    var lemon = FlavorBuilder.builder()
        .name("Limón")
        .build();
    var strawberry = FlavorBuilder.builder()
        .name("Fresa")
        .build();
    var candy = FlavorBuilder.builder()
        .name("Caramelo")
        .build();
    flavorRepository.saveAll(List.of(lemon, strawberry, candy));
    var tobacco = TobaccoBuilder.builder()
        .manufacturer(manufacturer)
        .add(lemon)
        .add(strawberry)
        .add(TobaccoPriceBuilder.builder().build())
        .add(TobaccoPriceBuilder.builder().build())
        .build();
    var tobacco2 = TobaccoBuilder.builder()
        .manufacturer(manufacturer)
        .add(candy)
        .add(lemon)
        .add(TobaccoPriceBuilder.builder().build())
        .add(TobaccoPriceBuilder.builder().build())
        .build();
    var tobacco3 = TobaccoBuilder.builder()
        .manufacturer(manufacturer)
        .add(candy)
        .add(TobaccoPriceBuilder.builder().build())
        .add(TobaccoPriceBuilder.builder().build())
        .build();
    tobaccoRepository.saveAll(List.of(tobacco, tobacco2, tobacco3));

    var queryString =
        lemon.getCode() + "=" + lemon.getName() + "&" + candy.getCode() + "=" + "camarelo"; // 'camarelo' is wrong on purpose

    webTestClient
        .get().uri(PUBLIC_TOBACCOS_ENDPOINT + "?" + queryString)
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk()
        .expectBodyList(TobaccoContentResponse.class)
        .value(tobaccos -> assertThat(tobaccos)
            .hasSize(3)
            .extracting("name")
            .containsExactly(
                tobacco2.getName(),
                tobacco.getName(),
                tobacco3.getName()
            )
        );

    await().atMost(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .untilAsserted(() -> assertThat(searchRepository.findAll()).hasSize(1));
}
```

As you can see, at the end of the test I'm waiting until there is some searches in the database, I'm using a real database in a docker container that is scale up every time I run the CI pipeline in GitHub Actions.

I can't understand **why is the test passing in local machine and failing consistenly in the CI pipeline?**

I also tried to increase the timeout without success.

Comment: Why is your controller transactional? Your listener method should be transactional not your controller. Also **why** is it failing? Isn't the size 1? (Do you have multple tests for this, leading to 2 or 3 results instead of 1?). But for starters move the `@Transactional` to the proper place.

Comment: I'm using transactional because of hibernate search, the repository I'm calling in the controller is for full text search. Hibernate search needs a transaction by default to perform the search, I will try to move the transactional to the repository level. I have also updated the test code, I forgot to mention that I have a `deleteAll` before each test, thats why I'm asserting always 1, but the test in the pipeline says size 0

Comment: Making your controller transasctional, the web layer, is a bad idea. YOur controller should call a service method that is transactional.

Comment: Ok, could you elaborate more about why is a bad idea? I moved the transactional to the repository class (is some kind of service in the end) and is failing by the same reason, timing out because there are no searches created in the database.

Comment: Do you want your transactional to fail when something goes wrong rendering/writing the response? As that is what you have achieved now, tied your transactionality to the success of the request/response cycle. Also the `@Transactional` on your controller doesn't work for the listener as that is `@Async` and thus uses  a different tx.